# Trigger function always raising exception when checking if values don't equal select query

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have a trigger which checks if the status of the row being referenced in the new record is either 'IN PROGRESS or 'ACCEPTED', however, it's not working as expected and always raises an exception even when I make sure that the record has a status of either 'IN PROGRESS' or 'ACCEPTED'.

Here's the tables involved:

```
Problem     | Ticket
------------+-------------
problem_id  | ticket_id
status      | problem_id


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION status_check()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT status FROM customer_problem WHERE problem_id = NEW.problem_id) 
             != 'IN PROGRESS' OR 
        (SELECT status FROM customer_problem WHERE problem_id = NEW.problem_id)
             != 'ACCEPTED' 
        THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Problem status not IN PROGRESS or ACCEPTED';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END
    $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



CREATE TRIGGER check_status_bef
BEFORE INSERT ON ticket 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE status_check();
```

I also tried using IF, IF-ELSE in case that made any difference, it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

That's unsurprising.

A condition like

```
WHERE x <> 'a' OR x <> 'b'
```

must always return `TRUE`, because nothing can be equal to two different things simultaneously (not that many people wouldn't try, but that's OT).